# Django - How to make migrations locally within an application while overriding User or Group model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an application 'registration' in which I am trying to add an extra field in Django auth groups. I have successfully implemented it using monkey patching. However, when I post this application to someone else and they run 'migrate', the build fails stating the reason that the newly added field does not exists. The reason being that when I created the migrations, the migration files were not created in my 'registration' application, instead, they were created in the Django.contrib.auth application.

How can I get past this problem?

Comment: Don't that 'someone else' need to run `makemigrations` first? Or you're copying Models and DB together?

Comment: Someone else is not supposed to run 'makemigrations' first. That is the requirement. Whenever we install a 3rd party registration package, they also ask us to just 'migrate' and not to run both the commands. This is where my requirement come from :(

Comment: More than that, Travis CI build is also failing saying that the field does not exists. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a dummy migration file in my application - 'registration'. Inside this migration, I created the column manually by executing an SQL Query so that the build does not fail. I'll post the code here.

```
def check_and_add_column(apps, schema_editor):
  import sqlite3
  conn = sqlite3.connect('db7.sqlite3')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  result = [True for i in cur.execute('PRAGMA table_info(auth_group)') if i[1] == 'is_auto_assign']

  if not result:
      cur.execute('ALTER TABLE auth_group ADD COLUMN is_auto_assign BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE')

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0001_initial'),
  ]

  operations = [
      migrations.RunPython(check_and_add_column,),

      # If you need to run SQL directly from here
      # migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE auth_group ADD COLUMN is_auto_assign BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE"),
  ]
```